# Not able to res.send() server response, but able to console.log the same response with Express

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm working on a custom integration solution using Express routes and after making a fetch call to firebase I need the response to my server to be the one coming from firebase to show me any issues (such as authentication errors) coming from there.

I've been trying to display the response by using res.send(), but it throws me a "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON" error, but when console.logging that same response it gives me the correct response (which is an authentication error). What's the deal with that?

Here's the code:

```
router.route("/bankval").get (fetchAirtabeleRecords, (req, res) => {

    fetch(`https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/integratedData.json?auth=${FIREBASESECRET}`,{
    method: 'PUT',
    headers:
    {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + FIREBASESECRET,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    body: JSON.stringify({bankValuation: res.bankVal}) // correct values here
})

.then((res) => res.json())

.then(res.send(res)) // This throws me the error

.then((res)=> { console.log('response: ', res); }) // This works and displays expected "error: 'Unauthorized request.' from firebase, but it's only in console, so it's not good enough."


// .then(res.send({bankValuation: res.bankVal}))   // this works, but if authentication error occurs it still displays the correct data, when it's obviously not sent to firebase. Only using this for testing purposes.

.catch(err=> { console.log('error: ',err); }) })
```

I'm pretty new to this, so maybe I'm doing this completely backwards or something, but any input is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You override res, so try this:

```
.then((resp) => resp.json())

.then((resp) => res.send(resp))

.then((resp)=> { console.log('response: ', resp); })
```

Comment: Oh, man! That did it!!! Thank you so much. For so many hours I tried to figure it out. Could you briefly expand on what the deal was in a little more detail? Thanks again.

Comment: You have `res` variable here `(req, res) => {` and then when you write below `res` here `(res) => res.json()` you override custom `res` variable which have method `send`. So when you execute `res.send` your `res` is already just JSON which don't have `send` method